# How do I remove these fence post spikes?

Tags: fence, removal, post

I want to buy these:

[image]

To replace my existing ones:

[image]

I want to remove the old ones. What is the easiest way to pull them out?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say to use a [farm jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_(device)#Farm_jack).

[image]

Use a pry-bar or a 2x4 and a block of wood till you can fit a farm jack under it.
happy jacking.

Comment: Including a picture of a farm jack would be helpful since not everyone may be familiar with that type of jack.

Comment: I would think just about anything you could use as a class 1 lever would be helpful here. Obviously, being careful not to slip off the spike or snap the lever would be idea. Worst case scenario, some of these things can be tapped side to side in all 4 vertical directions to loosen it up also.

Comment: It's called a highlift Jack  in my world.  But then there are happy little trees in my world thanks to Bob Ross.